# Search facility within a form MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I want to create a Search box on a form.

I want the user to be able to lookup a persons name and a list of results appear below, the user then clicks on the required persons name.

That's the easy bit.

However I want this record then to be added to the 'Form' along with hidden id parameter.

So that a user can then click submit and it submits the persons name plus other fields.

The issue I have is that with the Search box I need an Html.Beginform but I also need a form to Submit the final records. I can't get my head round doing this as I would need a nested Form which I have heard isn't good practice. I know the Search button form could be part of the main form however I don't want to submit the whole form just for a name lookup.

Ideally making some sort of AJAX call with partial views might be the answer but even with AJAX call I'd still need a form within a form.

Hope you can help a newbie.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple way briefly.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("save", "record"))
{
//your main form
<a id="lookup">find a person</a>
}

<div class="hidden" id="lookupdialog">
<form id="lookupform">  //Form is optional - just for 'postable' area indication

    //lookup form
         <input type="text" id="query">
     <a id="search">search</a>

</form>
</div>
```

So you have a main form visible, and a lookup form hidden. Then you use javascript to show the dialog. Something like in jquery:

```
$('#lookup').click(/*show #lookupdialog in a dialog*/);
```

So now you have your secondary form visible. When user clicks search, you'd send request to the server.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/persons/search",
       data: {query: $(#query).text()},
       success: function(data)
       {

           //show the list of persons found

       }
     });
```

Then, when user selects a person you'd close the dialog and save id of the selected item to you main form.